# Date format changing issue Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

All,

I want date format in dd/MMM/yyyy format below is the code i am using.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:@"dd/MMM/yyyy"];

NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

But in the dateString i am getting in **Oct 21,2014** which is diffrent how can i get in  "21/Oct/2014" format please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling `setDateStyle:` instead of `setDateFormat:`

Use this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];  
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

This code outputs "22/Oct/2014"